# Typing useReducer in React with Enum type with different payload types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am writing reducer function which accepts action with type property whos type is Enum type and action payload depends on Enum type.

I know that I can provide different payload types for each enum type using union types, but  I have one action which payload is Date and all other actions have payload type of number.

**What I've tried**

```
enum DatePickerActionType {
    PICK_YEAR = 'PICK_YEAR',
    PICK_MONTH = 'PICK_MONTH',
    PICK_DATE = 'PICK_DATE',
    PICK_HOURS = 'PICK_HOURS',
    PICK_MINUTES = 'PICK_MINUTES',
}

type DatePickerAction =
    | {
          type: DatePickerActionType.PICK_DATE;
          payload: Date;
      }
    | {
          type: DatePickerActionType;
          payload: number;
      };

const datePickerReducer = (state: DatePickerValue, action: DatePickerAction): DatePickerValue => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DatePickerActionType.PICK_DATE: {
            const a = action.payload;
        }
        //...
    }
};
```

However typescript still shows me action.type as number or Date when action type is PICK_DATE
[image: Reducer function]

Is there way to define payload type as number for all actions except on enum type or I should go with union type defining all actions separately?

```
type DatePickerAction =
    | {
          type: DatePickerActionType.PICK_DATE;
          payload: Date;
      }
    | {
          type: DatePickerActionType.PICK_HOURS;
          payload: number;
      }
    | {
          type: DatePickerActionType.PICK_MINUTES;
          payload: number;
      }
    | {
          /**... */
      };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Exclude` the specific enum:

```
// ...

type DatePickerAction =
    | {
        type: DatePickerActionType.PICK_DATE;
        payload: Date;
    }
    | {
        type: Exclude<DatePickerActionType, DatePickerActionType.PICK_DATE>;
        payload: number;
    };


const datePickerReducer = (state: DatePickerValue, action: DatePickerAction): DatePickerValue => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DatePickerActionType.PICK_DATE: {
            const a = action.payload; // Date
            break;
        }
        default: {
            const a = action.payload; // number
        }
        //...
    }
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAIghgF2ABQJYGMDWwBOBBdBVAexABUBPAB2CgG8AoKZqZASQGEBpAfQE0AongBKUALxQA5O278hwyQBomLGbwCyAeQByZABLipanlt16lK5sZh4yAw9M68bdiy1ZOeezQFVhAZQdjbz9-N1VPdTZtHztAiUdZKJi4iwBfBgYEalp4JDQsXAA1OAAbMFoJOBAKAG5M7JpYRBQMbHxCEhBxSygAH3pe90bgAC5m-LbcAiJSShoAOmtbAXr3dyo4ClLiOAATcbzgNZYM9wHGdZYR8YEAD3RyveAAHiOC9pmu+eBFCdbCh1ZuQcktPC4BAA+E5XTbbXYHKDgCAAI1wMKgaXqDHQpAAzggoHsWh9cMJgHswOhcIYABQElqHElTHAlcq-KBwTqkJmTQFfUgASl5APabIq4khg3ceIA7qgEOgABZQWlc4ELEaC6VXKDoOB43LM-nckGLZZ2caXXXuXEgAmcwzqroLOE7fa1KAAei9-yGupROGAcEwGPcZ11zwAZnAwKUEFb-Vc7Q64E7Ta6tu69p6fUjIGicEnMcWfQty70MligA)